# Saving the generated numpy random arrays in order without using lists in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, random

I am trying to make couple of random arrays with `numpy.random.poisson`. I want to save each data sets in the order that they are generated. Now I am using list for doing that, I was wondering if there is a better way to do that which could have easy access to each set afterwards?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randint(0, 255, (250, 250, 3)) 
total = np.zeros(data.shape)
listOfData = []
number = 10 #It could be any number
for i in range(number):
       new_total = np.random.poisson(lam=data)
       listOfData.append(new_total.flatten())
       total += new_total
firstSet = np.array(listOfData[0]).reshape(data.shape)
```

My data is a 3-D array.

Comment: What do you mean by "easy access to each set"?

Comment: I mean I could use them afterwards with just calling their index from the place that have been saved. Like say I could use the first generated data set with just calling something like ListOfData[0].

Comment: Why don't you just not `.flatten()` when you're adding to the list?

Comment: I just added that because I thought that it would make my list more manageable but even removing that would not change the fact that I still need to make it an array again in order to work on that. I was hoping that there might be a way to skip that step.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, `type(listOfData[0])` already gives: `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: I guess I was wrong about that, thank you for mentioning that.

Comment: No worries, hope it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `listOfData[0]` is already an `ndarray`, so you can skip that part.